# Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR is returning a wrong value?

Tags: java, week-number

I tried getting week of the year through below code but it always returns "3", I even set the timezone to GMT but still returning the same value(`"3"`). Please help me out over here

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
Date date = formatter.parse("14-10-2014")
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
```

Comment: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 6):

You're setting the *minutes* not the *month*. It sounds like it's parsing this as 2014-01-14T00:10:00, and that January 14th 2014 is in the third week. You want `MM` for months, not `mm`.

(I'd also encourage you to use `yyyy-MM-dd` if you get a chance to change the format entirely - that's ISO-8601 compliant...)